# Alternative for observeForever using Transformations.map

Tags: android, kotlin, transformation, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

I am observing a liveData to do some queries using *observeForever* inside ViewModel,

```
  query.observeForever {
      //
    }
```

the logic is working fine, but i can't remove the observer in *onCleared* as i have no access to lifecycle from viewModel and i shouldn't, i tried with Transformation.map

```
 Transformations.map(query){
//
    }
```

and failed to observe the changes.any suggestions how to use Transformation.map to listen to livedata changes and act on them

Comment: You should using Transformations.map, this method return to LiveData, observe it in UI you want

Comment: i ended up using my classic way of doing things, putting observer in the fragment for the livedata in the viemodel and upon its changes firing my function.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your viewmodel extend `LifecycleObserver` like this -

```
class MyViewModel() : LifecycleObserver {
   val queryObserver = Observer {
     // do stuff
   }

   @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
   fun onResumed() {
    query.observeForever(queryObserver)
   }

   @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
   fun onPasued() {
    query.removeObserver(queryObserver)
   }
}
```

Don't forget to add `getLifecycle().addObserver(mViewModel)` in your Activity!